# How can I make a javascript function run before submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using a javascript function to append values to a hidden div, which has to be submitted to the database.
The javascript function needs to run when the Submit button is clicked, append the values, and *then* the form should be submitted.
My js code to append the values like this:

```
$('#submitButton').click( function () {
  $('#submitField').val('[');
  $.each(Selector.selected_options, function (i) {
    if (i == 0){
      $('#submitField').val($('#submitField').val() + this.id);
    } else {
      $('#submitField').val($('#submitField').val() + ', ' + this.id);
    }
  });
  $('#submitField').val($('#submitField').val()+']');
});
```

(This output is evaluated as an array)
I am using Rails `form_tag` and `text_field_tag`
How can I make this function run (and finish) right before the form is submitted to the database?

Comment: I think it should already do what you want. Instead of using `$("#submitField").val()` repeatedly, I suggest accumulating the value into a string and putting it into the `val()` once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your all code into onSubmit event

like.. -

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$(#form-id).submit.preventDefault()`

then the function dealing with the div and then an `$(#form-id).trigger('submit')` to submit the form after the div has been populated

```
$('#FORM-ID').submit( function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#submitField').val('[');
  $.each(Selector.selected_options, function (i) {
    if (i == 0){
      $('#submitField').val($('#submitField').val() + this.id);
    } else {
      $('#submitField').val($('#submitField').val() + ', ' + this.id);
    }
  });
  $('#submitField').val($('#submitField').val()+']');
  $('#FORM-ID').trigger('submit');
});
```